# Why doesn't where and take combination with Query Builder in TypeORM work?

Tags: typescript, graphql, typeorm

I am using the query builder from typeorm.

It works with my `where` function and it works with the `take` function. WIth where it returns 5 items (that is correct) and when first is `3` it returns 3 items. But it doesn't work with both together. Then it returns always only one item. What am I doing wrong?

```js
public async search(first?: number): Promise<Item[]> {
    const findConditions: FindConditions<Item> = {
        deleted: IsNull(),
    };

    return this.itemRepository
        .createQueryBuilder()
        .select("item")
        .from(Item, "item")
        .where(findConditions)
        .take(first)
        .getMany();
}
```

Comment: use limit() instead of take

Comment: @Youba i've done that, doesn't change anything :(

Comment: Please edit the question and add examples of what exactly you expect to get on each case, using mock data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am having the wrong syntax. Cause I use the query builder with my `itemRepository`, I have not to use the `select` and `from` functions, because that creates a wrong `FROM` statement.

So this works:

```js
public async search(first?: number): Promise<Item[]> {
    const findConditions: FindConditions<Item> = {
        deleted: IsNull(),
    };

    return this.itemRepository
        .createQueryBuilder()
        .where(findConditions)
        .take(first)
        .getMany();
}
```